# git checkout master branch display uncommitted files

Tags: git

I am checking out in my master branch but when i checking out in my master branch it displays uncommitted files even if i discard these files and again checkout to my master branch from my feature branch.

Comment: Sorry, it is impossible to answer to a "question" like that. Please take your time to phrase your question such that it people can understand what you did, what your issue is and what your question is. Thanks.

Comment: do you use a graphic client or with command line ?

Comment: Do you you have `git config core.autocrlf` set to true?

Comment: What does the term _uncommitted files_ mean? Are they files in index (ready for commit), files in working tree or not indexed at all? In the last case, it is the normal behavior. Git does not touch any files you haven’t told it to take care of.

Comment: @arkascha just checking out in my branch there is many files showing as unstaged.
mmm i am using source tree client.
Melebius uncommitted files mean unstaged files or showing as files that i made changes but i didn't made any changes to those files.

Comment: Probably the branch was checked out before and already had modified files.

Answer (score -1):

Switching branch in Git tries to preserve uncommitted changes. Such changes don’t belong to any branch until they become a commit. If it’s not able to preserve the changes, Git even refuses to switch the branch:

```
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        tests/ts/control.cpp
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

The command `git checkout` works in two modes. One is used to switch branches (that’s my example above), the other to remove uncommitted changes. To use the second mode, you must specify a path, for example `.` for the current directory.

```
git checkout .
```

which is equivalent to

```
git reset --hard
```